# Show Dialog when touch notification on Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I already built push notification by using Firebase Cloud Messaging on Eclipse Project. Now I want to make dialog with OK button when I touch the notification on status bar.

Can anyone help me? or suggest how to handle it? 
FYI, anytime (when the apps on background or in foreground) if I touch the notification on top it will show a dialog box.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to use a pending intent with your notification that defines how to handle the notification click.

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DialogActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
             // YOUR Notification parameters
            .build();

    notification.contentIntent = pendingNotificationIntent;
```

See that the intent points to a **DialogActivity**, so we need to create a DialogActivity to handle the intent. See the code below :

```
public class DailogActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get Extra data from intent if you pass something
    // Intent intent = getIntent();
    // Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    // Show the popup dialog
    showNewDialog(0);
}

public void showNewDialog(int id) {
    // TODO : Code to show the new dialog
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I'll try it first. :)

Comment: Can u explain to me, where to use 'pendingNotificationIntent' on DialogActivity?

Comment: it is not required, pendingNotification intent is just used  with the notification , to handle its actions.

Comment: I'm still cant get the dialog pop up sir.

Comment: what's the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Sorry, I get it now. I miss to put some syntax on my AndroidManifest. Now it works sir. Thanks a lot.